# Can't interface with FFMPEG using cv2.videocapture

Tags: python, opencv

i'm using Vantech DVR (vp-863ahd) and I want to interface with another type (FFMPEG, MJPEG) but i can't find the right URL for cv2.videocapture. I already tried all the url on https://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=Vantech# but none of them work

It works fine on JPEG url but the fps is so low about 0.9 fps

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://username:password@ip_address/cgi-bin/net_jpeg.cgi?ch=2')

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: think you've got the username/password in the URL wrong, see https://serverfault.com/a/371918 for an example.  note you need an `@` before the hostname/ip address

Comment: I tried that but it still don't work